# In PhantomJS, how to limit the maximum redirection?

Tags: phantomjs, redirect

When a script has a redirect loop we get an error in Google Chrome that says

```
Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.
```

*Rem : Google Chrome allows a maximum of 20 redirects,*

In PhantomJS, is it possible to limit the the maximum redirection (eg to match Chrome and Firefox).

Comment: Yes, with a little event magic. Do you have an example page?

Comment: You can test with [httpbin.org](http://httpbin.org/) site.
eg : 302 Redirects 30 times. http://httpbin.org/redirect/30